# How to "blend" between two colors?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, blending

I've this image:

[image]

I'd like to softly "blend" the borders of the "grey" one, let it fade to white, so not a heavy separation between the two colors. Not sure how its call in Graphic Design; blend right?

How can I do in Photoshop? (I'm using the CS6).

Comment: How can I make a gradient between two photos? Or best: a photo and a background...

Comment: Is this the photo you are working with are you looking for a general method to work on any photo? If it's just for this photo, I can think of many ways to recreate it (namely, using Illustrator) if you need this concept to apply to other (raster) photos, there may be other ways to do it.

Comment: I need to apply to raster photos. Which "border" are not white, and I need to "grandient" the borders to white

Comment: I guess blend would be the correct term then.

Comment: Nice :) How can I do it? Maybe with a brush manually to the borders?

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the white (background) in your image using the Magic Wand Tool:

[image: selection]

Then apply a feather to your selection by **Right Click → Feather**

Now adjust your Levels (only over that selection) - I dragged everything to the [lowest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOJnY.png).

[image: result]

If you make it a bigger feather, you will get a smoother "blend".

Comment: How do I apply a feather to my selection?

Comment: Right click → Feather (I've updated my answer, sorry about that)